# Can anyone use this Journalism tool on UK Public Bodies?

Tags: releasing-data, uk, journalism

Are you looking for information on public bodies: especially links to their website and FOI request on "what do they know"?

Comment: StackExchange sites have no issue with people self-answering their question, but can you please [edit] this so that your question is a question only (and the answer the answer). It also helps if you describe what that list is (this is an international site, after all). Also: if you are affiliated with that list, please say so. Thanks.

Comment: This list is not just a scrape of https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/body/list/all, is it? If so, what is it additional value? And is it being kept up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

The database website is a flat file list of websites and their re;evant details. http://datamineruk.github.io/journo-tools/uk-public-bodies/

At a guess this a Journalist tool, and even if its a little out of date the link to FOI are relevant and up to date.

It's date and I hope that this tool gives convenient links to do research on public bodies.

I have now affiliation to the site, I just thought it would be useful to anyone. And rather than just tweeting I thought it might be relevant to someone.

[image: dataminerUK journalism tools of UK public bodies]

Look you can see from the image what it's about. It has a listing of UK public bodies. It's sortable. And gives links to the main website and the FOI (what do they know site)